# Why does Camel call my endpoint's start() method twice?

Tags: java, service, methods, apache-camel

I was using the start() method to instantiate the connection to the feed I was using and then stop() to tear it down, but after creating the Endpoint, Camel proceeds to call start() twice in a row on it

while obviously easy to work around by either checking whether its been started once already, or (as I did) just moving the starting code into the constructor of Endpoint - it's making me think I don't understand what the start() method is trying to achieve (the documentation helpfully suggests: start() starts a service ... grrreat

why would this happen twice?

---

incidentally createEndpointUri() gets called too... which makes me rather suspicious since this is a 'lazy loader for when a uri hasn't been supplied' ... except that one has been supplied ... so I wonder if some secondary instantiation is occuring for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extend ServiceSupport which has doStart | doStop methods, and can keep track of the state of your class. Then Camel knows the state and wont invoke doStart twice.

Comment: ah okay, I should have Overriden doStart() not start(). It works now thanks very much for answer. It would be cool if start() was final to stop that kind of mistake happening. I don't suppose you have any idea why createEndpointUri() is getting called? It ought to have it's URI already and it isn't a required override, but the code fails without it... maybe this is a separate question to be honest

Comment: You should put this somewhere in the documents

Comment: Good idea, I have updated the javadoc of the class with more details: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/4f7255af05a895ee932e5506605e55ceefd35de5